# Execute Pyhton file - Output terminal

Tags: ros, launch-file

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

How can I display something from a Phyton file on the terminal?

I start the launch file with the node from the pyhton file, but I do not get back the informations on the terminal. For example when I have the order "print 5", shouldn’t I see the number 5 on the terminal after I launch the file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50313/execute-pyhton-file---output-terminal/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [rospy logging overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Logging) page for more details.

You can use

```
number = 5
rospy.loginfo("%d", number)
rospy.logwarn("%d", number)
```

If you run your Python node from a launch file you need to put `output="screen"` inside the `node` tag to see info messages.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to specify output="screen" in the launch file.  See the [xml syntax of node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node) for more info.

And for the record, the programming language is 'python' as in Monty Python or the snake. : )

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2012-12-12**:
Thanks ;)